# How to select multiple contacts at a time?

Tags: android, database, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I retrieve phonebook contacts to my application by using following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  
                                            Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);      
}
```

But I want to select multiple contacts and upload those to a DB. Is this possible and if so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could query the content provider directly inside your activity so the user can select multiple contact. This can be achieved using the contacts contract. For more information you can look at the [api documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) or this [tutorial blog post](http://www.app-solut.com/blog/2011/03/working-with-the-contactscontract-to-query-contacts-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
     people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int position=0;
    Cursor q=db.query(mProfile,new String[]{"person_name"},"person_name"+"!='"+null+"'",null,null, null, null);
    people.moveToFirst();
        int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);    
        while(!people.isAfterLast()) {
            Cursor o=db.query(mProfile,new String[]{"person_name"},"person_name"+"='"+people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex)+"'",null,null, null, null);
            if(!(o.getCount()>0))
            {  
            mConname.add(position, people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex));
            try{
                String contactId = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String hasPhone = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                    hasPhone = "true";
                else
                    hasPhone = "false" ;
                if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
                {
                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                    while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                    {
                        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        mConno.add(position,phoneNumber);

                    }
                    phones.close(); 
                }   
                if(hasPhone=="false")
                {   mConname.remove(position);
                }   
                else
                    position++;
            }       
            catch(Exception e)
            { 

            }
        }
            people.moveToNext();
        }
```

use  the sqlite and store it

Comment: what is" mProfile",can you give more details