# How do I access the android phone book contacts & selecting multiple contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select multiple contacts at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675670/how-to-select-multiple-contacts-at-a-time)

I want to access the android phone book contacts 
through my application and also select multiple contact(as per my 
choice) from phone book...please help me to find out a suitable way...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is using Content Providers.

Check out this on the Developers site..

[Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)